# Get the date from file and put to sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have simple question probably but can't figure out how to achieve that in 'secure way'. I have lot of file names which within contains date and time, what i need to do is to extract from it year, month and day and then insert it to sql server database to datetime field. Unfortunetly i cannot point from right of the file and tell this number is on this position as number of digits within date are changing right? Do you know some good way to do it?

Examples:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-yyy-**2015_5_6**-23_20_12_132.csv    ' have to take 2015_5_6
rrrrrrrrrr-tttttttt-**2015_11_12**-23_20_12_1.csv    ' have to take 2015_11_12
fffffff-eeeeee-**2015_4_28**-20_45_0_671.csv         ' have to take 2015_4_28
```

Comment: Are the * included in file names or you have just used it to highlight the text you need?

Comment: Shame on me! * cannot be inside Windows filenames ;-)

Comment: no without stars sorry i made mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with regular expression

```
    Dim fileNames As String() = {"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-yyy-2015_5_6-23_20_12_132.csv", "rrrrrrrrrr-tttttttt-2015_11_12-23_20_12_1.csv", "fffffff-eeeeee-2015_4_28-20_45_0_671.csv"}

    Dim rx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("-(\d+_\d+_\d+)-")

    Dim matches As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection

    For Each fileName As String In fileNames
        matches = rx.Matches(fileName)

        Console.WriteLine(matches(0).Groups(1))
    Next
```

Comment: is this also be ok if the digits number will be diffrent for instance for day (29) or also for seconds (59) it always pick up correct date? Is there any other way do do it without regex?

Comment: if i got only one string how then to do this instead of list?

Comment: First comment: yes the regular expression will match any sequence of at least one digit separated by underscores, enclosed by two delimiting "-" chars. However I tought you need just the date part, the provided expression cannot match seconds. In your question example you didn't mention seconds.

Comment: Second comment: can you provide a sample string?